# Does hatching a Pokémon count towards my Daily Bonus?

Tags: pokemon-go

I hatched a Squirtle this morning before catching anything and I  don't think it told me I'd continued my Daily Bonus streak. Hatching Pokémon counts as catching with regards to Pokédex entries, so was my streak continued or does hatching not count towards it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, hatching Pokémon does ***not*** count towards your Daily Bonus streak. Shortly after hatching my Squirtle, I caught a Pidgey. On the rewards screen for catching the Pidgey, I was notified that I extended my streak.

[image: Journal with hatch timestamps]
[image: Rewards screen for catching Pidgey]